# Add image to animated gif using javascript

Tags: javascript, gif

I'd like to, using javascript if possible, add images (small stars) to an existing animated GIF.  There can be as little as 0 stars, as many as probably about 10, but this number is not known until the gif is loaded on the page.  It'd be a bonus if the stars "float" around the image.

A cursory search around SO and Google resulted in not much on the subject.  I'm wondering if I'm not searching using the right terms.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or give me an example of something similar?

Comment: Are you just talking about overlaying addition images on top of another image?

Comment: dig `js snowflakes` examples on the Web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/CaseyRule/e0a98pdu/3/

```
var w = $('#gifContainer').width() - 12;
var h = $('#gifContainer').height() - 12;
var stars = [];

function randomlyPositionStar( star ) {
    var x = (Math.random() * w);
    var y = (Math.random() * h);
    star.style.transform =  'translate('+x+'px,'+y+'px)';
}

for(var i = 0; i<10; i++ ){
    var starSrc = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/archive/6/60/20060130131745!LinkFA-star.png';
    var star = new Image();
    star.src = starSrc;
    star.className = 'star';
    randomlyPositionStar( star );
    $('#gifContainer').append(star);
    stars.push( star );
}

setInterval( function() {
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * stars.length);
    randomlyPositionStar( stars[i] );
}, 100);
```